# Passing an int from native code (jni) to java, modify it in java and pass back via arguments

Tags: java, android, reference, java-native-interface, arguments

I have a thread in my native Code (c++) and this thread calls a callback function in java with a passed integer in agument.
The callback function in java should modify this integer and returns true or false.
The native code sould work with the new (modified) integer.

Example Code:

C-Code:

```
doSomething()
{
     int id = 5;
     callback_fct(&id)
}

callback_fct(int* id)
{
    jclass integerClass = (env)->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID midConstructor = (env)->GetMethodID(integerClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jmethodID midIntValue = (env)->GetMethodID(integerClass, "intValue", "()I");
    jobject integerObject = (env)->NewObject(integerClass, midConstructor, *id);

            //id should be 5
    int res = env->CallIntMethod(appl_object, mid, integerObject);

    *id= env->CallIntMethod(integerObject, midIntValue);
            //id should be 99 now
}
```

Java-Code:

```
private int callback( Integer ID)
{
    Log.i("JavaWrapper", "callback");
    Log.i("JavaWrapper", "Old ID: " + ID); //should be 5
    ID = 99;
    Log.i("JavaWrapper", "New ID: " + ID);  //should be 99
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone give me a short example for this?

Thanks

Comment: All Integer's are immutable.  Both primitive and boxed integers are immutable (with respect of passing in arguments and having it modified).  You can work around this by creating your own class (encapsulating an integer) or using an Integer array (and setting first item to the value, to modify the callback replaces the value but reuses the same array object).  So this is what you shall be passing.

Comment: It also helps your case by spending the time filling in personal details and earning at least one some reputation with the site, but maybe you have no intention of doing this, hence your user1002933 username. Best of luck getting a useful answer.